# Grammatical name

Tags: syntactic-analysis

What is the grammatical name and function of 
"The variety of vitamins and nutrients in green beans" help prevent many health problems

Comment: The question is too broad (ho, ho ‘green beans’) unclear as it seems the sentence ends with *…green beans*. The function of "what" exactly?

Comment: It's a noun phrase that functions as the subject of the sentence.

Comment: @LucianSava You should put that into an answer.

Comment: The variety helps. Although this old question seems past help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English grammar there are two main parts of a sentence: the subject and the predicate.

The subject usually appears before the predicate to show what the sentence is about, or who or what performs the action.

The subject of a sentence may be one word or several words. Commonly it is a noun, a pronoun, or a noun phrase. Sometimes it can be even an entire clause:

> **What he had already forgotten about computer repair** could fill whole volumes.

In your example:

> **The variety of vitamins and nutrients in green beans** helps prevent many health problems.

the part in bold is a noun phrase that functions as the subject of the sentence.

Source: http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/subjects.htm